# Why isn't the value updating in my React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lifecycle, use-effect

This seems to be a problem unique to react as I am unable to replicate it using plain JavaScript. The issue is that I use a state variable within a function, but the function will use the value that the variable had whenever the function was defined, rather than the current value of the variable:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
export default function Home() {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(0);
  const [f, setF] = useState(null);

  useEffect(function(){
    setF(()=>function(){console.log(val)})
    setVal(2)
  },[])

  console.log("Value is", val)
  return (
    <div 
      onClick={f} 
      style={{
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
      }}
    >

    </div>
  )
}
```

After clicking the div, the output will be:

```
Value is 0
Value is 2
0
```

Clearly, the variable val is updated to be 2, but when the function f is run it prints out the value that val had when the function was defined rather than its new updated value.

I've worked around this by having the function be redefined any time the state values it depends on change, but this is less than ideal, as I would expect the function to always use the new value. It seems in regular javascript this does not occur, or at least I cannot figure out how to make it happen.

Why is this happening? is there a fix that can be made that does not require me to redefine the function? Is this unique to react?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Tuhin pointed out, the short answer is closures. When you define `setF(()=>function(){console.log(val)})`, val = 0 and at no point after that is the function definition changed, so `f` has closure over the value of val at the point of its creation. You can add `console.dir(f)` in your code to check it out: [image]

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `f` didn't update when `val` updated.
If you give to your `useEffect` the `val` as a dependency the problem will be solved.
You can see [it](https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-sea-7zh4r?file=/src/App.js:319-322).

Comment: Thanks and yes this is how I solved it initially, although I still don't understand why it is evaluating the value of `val` before the function is actually called. I thought it would evaluate `val` at the time the function is called?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you want to print recent `val` by the `f` function.

But The problem is,
`setF(()=>function(){console.log(val)})` <-- this line.

val will be always 0 as it is assigned once, and will be called by value, not by the reference. Just like how setTimeout works.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Comment: I can't recreate the problem using setTimeout. If I do `var o = 0; setTimeout(()=>console.log(o), 2000); o = 2;` the output will be `2`. I still don't understand why `val` is assigned at the time the function is defined rather than at the time it is ran? is there a specific section at the link you gave me that explains that?